# Steps to make native boot vhd boot in virtual box

Tags: windows-7, boot, virtualbox, virtualization

Apologies in advance if this has been previously discussed, I did my best attempt at searching and could not find what I was looking for.

My issue is that I have a windows 8 vhd I want to update to 8.1 and from what I understand the only way to do this is with a virtual box vm because windows will think its not a virtual drive and it will install (I also hope to be able to native boot the vhd again once updated to 8.1). When I try to boot the vhd in virtual machine I get the error "The boot configuration data file doesnt contain valid information for an operating system, error 0xc0000098. I have been trying to follow this suggestion: https://superuser.com/a/571912/317553 but I am stuck where it says to "Select the file "BCD" in the folder "BCD" and click "open". Take note that the file has no file ending." because I cant find any bcd file or folder. So my question is, is what is the simplest way to accomplish this, and more importantly is it possible ?

What I have tried so far:

"Use a tool to install a BCD-Bootsector to the drive. I used NeoSmart's EasyBCD: Start the tool and choose BCD Deployment. Under "Create Bootable External Media" choose the drive name of the mounted VHD and click on "Install BCD"." -from the answer in the provided link, and this produces the error I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Using a VM for updating would considerably slow the update process but it seems to be the only way
to update Win 8 VHD to Win 8.1. HYPER-V can run Windows 8 VHD so a second native installation of Windows 8 could serve as host for the update.

To make VHD bootable in VM use following steps:

A) Write a MBR and PBR record to VHD itself using bootsect:

(In Windows 8 using admin command prompt, assuming VHD is mapped to V:)

**bootsect /nt60 v: /mbr**

B) Using Disk Management **ensure VHD single partition is marked as active**, if not mark as active.

C) Create BCD inside VHD:

**bcdboot v:\windows /s v:**

If you are booted in Windows 8 VHD itself then V: would become C: !

One last thing. A Windows VHD installation is a native installation - it uses all computer hardware plus the virtual disk layer. A VM is a different computer hardware so you have to activate Windows again eventually.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have problems with BCD.
I had the same problems when booting from Windows 7 VHD (created with VirtualBox).
[This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799299%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) article from TechNet helped me too much (I will summarize it's content).

All you need to do is:

1. Attach that VHD using Diskpart (explained in that technet article) or use Disk Management
   (press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `diskmgmt.msc`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, choose `Action` menu -> `Attach VHD`).
2. Add boot entry using BCDTool (here is text from article)

   > Use the BCDboot tool, located in the \System32 directory of the VHD
   >   image or in Windows PE to copy the boot environment files and Boot
   >   Configuration Data (BCD) configuration from the \Windows directory in
   >   the VHD to the system partition. On a computer with BIOS firmware, the
   >   system partition is the active partition of the first hard disk. For
   >   example, to use BCDboot from the VHD image, at a command prompt, type:
   >   cd v:\windows\system32
   >   bcdboot v:\windows

   In this step I used Windows 7 installation disk (Win 8 will work the same way), booted from disk, get to Recovery and run command line. Then I typed that last 2 commands.
   (There may be a lot of alternative ways of doing this step by using tools, WinPE disks and so on).
3. Restart the computer, choose the OS and run.

**NOTE:** If you have UEFI-based computer then this will not work. Look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799299%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) again for instructions.

Hope it helps!